# How to retrieve the data of the apps and the system

Tags: iphone, ios, backup, data-synchronization, filesystem

Not sure if this is even possible, but it is very important for me and I could not read the answer yet.

Before iOS I had this Linux OS that is not a Android. I was able to retrieve a SQLite database that contained all the phone calls and messages I did. For each application I could find its path where the data have been stored as an XML or a SQLite most often. Then I could take this data into my computer and dig into this. Even it was possible to make this process automated by scripting.

I came to iOS recently. I set up everything and downloaded several apps. And I would like to construct a similar way of backing up my data. How can I access the phone real storage? Where is my data? Can I access root directory of this storage and dig into the data that the applications are storing? By this Files app I have just access to some few directories and nothing crucial.

I do not use iCloud.

I am aware that some applications would use its own web servers, so I would not have an access until they don't let me export my data. Let's say Pinterest or Strava could be an example.

But some very useful smaller apps like Thenics for example. There is a history of all my trainings I did. And I bet this is kept somewhere at my iPhone. I would like to get this into my own computer. How to do that?

Comment: What OS is your computer?

Comment: My primary one is Arch Linux, but I have also macOS and Windows if there is no option to communicate Arch Linux. By the way I use Local Send app to send files between iOS and Windows and that is quite fine, despite manual. But I cannot dig into real storage, just the Files, Documents, Photos etc.